# How to avoid array out of range error in mql4 indicator

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

How to deal with or handle/avoid the array out of range error here :

```
  for(int i=0; i<=ObjectsTotal()-1; i++)
    {
     string objName = ObjectName(0,i);
     if(StringFind(objName,"Last#")>=0)
       {
        string tempval= objName;
        string temtext= ObjectGetString(0,objName,OBJPROP_TEXT);

        StringReplace(tempval,"Last#","");
        int tempnum = (int)(tempval);
        for(int k=tempnum; k>=tempnum-20; k--)
          {
            
           if(
              RBuffer1[k] != EMPTY_VALUE)      
             {
              ObjectDelete(0,objName);
              DrawText("Last#"+tempnum,Time[tempnum],Low[tempnum],temtext+"_0","Arial",9,clrWhite);
              break;

             }
           else
              if(RBuffer2[k] != EMPTY_VALUE)    
                {
                 ObjectDelete(0,objName);
                 DrawText("Last#"+tempnum,Time[tempnum],Low[tempnum],temtext+"_1","Arial",9,clrWhite);
                 break;
                }
          }
       }
    }
```

I am sure there is something wrong with my logic but cant figure out what exactly , and the indicator works fine on some timeframes but on 2 ,3 timeframes it throws the error array out of range

This is   `for(int k=tempnum; k>=tempnum-20; k--)` where I am receiving the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the size of "RBuffer1" using "ArraySize":

```
      int iArrSize =  ArraySize(RBuffer1);               
      if (iArrSize >= 20) 
      {
         ...
      }
```

more importantly, the array index starts from 0 up to the predefined size (in your case 20 or 21). But you are trying to access the index 20 up to 41. Obviously, you will receive an "Array out of range" error message. Just change your code to something like:

```
      if (RBuffer1[k - 21] != EMPTY_VALUE) 
      {
         ...
      }
```